# Quickly re-create python string based on indices

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, match

This is a simple problem, but I realized that I'm stuck as how to *quickly* do the following in python:

Let's say I have the following string in Python3.x, length of 24 characters:

```
exstr1 = "BBBBBBDDDDDDHHHGHHFFGGFF"
```

I also have the following list which corresponds to indices based on the string above:

```
index = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Based on these indices, I would like to create a new string whereby each index above will change the character to 'S'

```
"SSBSSSDDSSSSSHSHSSSSSSSSF"
```

Now, in Python, you cannot directly manipulate a string. If I try the following:

```
for i in index:
    exstr1[i] = 'S'
```

I will get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

The inefficient solution is to create a `range(23)`, create a string of all `S` length 24 and if the "index" isn't in the range, access the original string and somehow change the value.

What is an efficient solution to generate the "S" string above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split exstr1 into a list of characters, perform all your operations on the list, then join it back together.

```
l = list(exstr1)
for i in index:
    l[i] = 'S'
new_str = ''.join(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list() method , apart from that you can also use list comprehension method :

```
exstr1 = "BBBBBBDDDDDDHHHGHHFFGGFF"

index = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]


data=[i for i in exstr1]

for i in index:
    data[i]='S'

print(data)
```

output:

```
['S', 'S', 'B', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'D', 'D', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'H', 'S', 'G', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in one line, you could do this:

```
"S".join([ xstr1[a+1:b] for a,b in zip([0]+index,index+[len(xstr1)]) ])
```

The idea is to extract subranges of xstr1 between the "S" positions and then join them with "S" in between each.   This approach assumes that the indexes in the list are in increasing order with no duplication.